# Window onload and onclick events

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys I’m trying to make simple weather app and I’ve run into an issue. Everything worked fine until I decided to make a function which would change Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa. I decided to make a function which I would call onclick event after window.load event, but for some reason it’s not working. When I use onclick element I get following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property ‘onclick’ of null

and when I add to it window.load nothing happens. Here is my JS:

```
// This won't work on github because openweatherapp requires payed version of api for https and github forces https

const ipApi = 'http://ip-api.com/json';
const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

fetch(ipApi)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
        let latitude = data.lat;
        let longitude = data.lon;
        let city = data.city;

        const openWeatherAppId = '********';
        const openWeatherUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&units=metric' + '&APPID=' + openWeatherAppId;

        fetchWeather(city, openWeatherUrl);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // If there is any error you will catch them here
        console.log(error);
    });


function fetchWeather(city, api) {
    fetch(api)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function(data) {

            let desc = data.weather[0].description;
            let temperature = data.main.temp;
            let icon = data.weather[0].icon;
            var iconSrc = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + icon + '.png';

            let myCity = createNode('h2');
            myCity.innerHTML = city;

            let myDesc = createNode('p');
            myDesc.innerHTML = desc;

            let myDiv = createNode('div');
            myDiv.setAttribute('id', 'temperatureDiv');

            let myTemp = createNode('p');
            myTemp.innerHTML = temperature;
            myTemp.setAttribute('id', 'temperature'); // Give ID to 'p' so I can use with DOM

            let myUnit = createNode('span');
            myUnit.innerHTML = 'Celsius';
            myUnit.setAttribute('id', 'unit'); // Give ID to 'p' so I can use with DOM

            let myIcon = createNode('img');
            myIcon.src = iconSrc;

            append(body, myCity);
            append(body, myDesc);
            append(body, myDiv);
            append(myDiv, myTemp);
            append(myDiv, myUnit);
            append(body, myIcon);

            changeUnits(temperature);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // If there is any error you will catch them here
            console.log(error);
        });    
}

function changeUnits (myTemperature) {
    let currentTemp = myTemperature; // This is current temperature in celsius

    if (document.getElementById('unit').innerHTML == 'Celsius') {
        document.getElementById('temperature').innerHTML = (currentTemp * 1.8 + 32).toFixed(0);
        document.getElementById('unit').innerHTML = 'Fahrenheit';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('temperature').innerHTML = currentTemp;
        document.getElementById('unit').innerHTML = 'Celsius';
    }
}

window.load = function () {
    document.getElementById('unit').onclick = changeUnits;
}

function createNode(element) {
    return document.createElement(element); // Create the type of element you pass in the parameters
}

function append(parent, el) {
    return parent.appendChild(el); // Append the second parameter(element) to the first one
}
```

Can anyone help me with this. Here is JSBin, so you see what is happening http://jsbin.com/jujifo/edit?html,js,console,output
I’m using openweather API so use http, so you can see code in action it won’t work on https

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 Note: Your API key can still be seen in the edit history of your question - you can't erase that! I would delete the question and post a new one if you don't have the right answer yet

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 I think a moderator can help you ^^

Comment: flag to `in need of moderator intervention` and ask if they can remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Window onLoad

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

You are trying to get an `element` before even exist.

See: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload#Notes)

Just assign the `onClick` handler on creation:

```
 myUnit = createNode('span');  
 myUnit.addEventListener('click', function(e) { changeUnits()})
 ...
```

See: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gugowupada/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was doing something wrong but could get it where and how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

An element with an ID of `unit` does not exist when the page loads, as it is made when your AJAX call happens.

Once the AJAX call happens, you should define `onclick` as a function (in the same way that you do with `window.onload`, not just a pointer to one, i.e.

```
document.getElementById("unit").onclick = function() {
    chnageUnits();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but when use it like that I get following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Answer (score 0):

You could just add event listener after creating the node, like this

```
    let myUnit = createNode('span');
    myUnit.addEventListener('click', changeUnits);
```

Working jsbin http://jsbin.com/xuvanen/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onload` instead of `window.load`. Try this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('unit').addEventListener('click', changeUnits);
}
```

Alternatively, in most modern browsers, you can use the `async` or `defer` attributes on the script tag to avoid the synchronous blocking behavior that is the default.